# Set default theme in Excel 2016

Tags: excel

I wish to use a custom theme as the default Theme in Excel 2016.

If that's not possible, I wish to use a custom template as the default template.

I have not been able to find anything on how to set a default theme, but a default template should be possible, according to [this Microsoft guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-in-Word-or-Excel-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904#__make_my_changes) that I will quote here, in case the page is offline or removed in the future:

`Part 1:`

Apply your custom theme to a blank workbook and then [save it as a template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-workbook-as-a-template-855d15bd-39ec-458b-8af8-456517a661d7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) named Book.xltx.

`Part 2:`

1. If you’re saving a workbook to a template for the first time, start by setting the **default personal templates location**.
2. Open the workbook you want to use as a template.
3. Click **File > Export**.
4. Under **Export**, click **Change File Type**.
5. In the **Workbook File Types** box, double-click **Template**.
6. In the **File name** box, type the name you want to use for the template.
7. Click **Save**, and then close the template.

I set the *default personal templates location* to `C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents\Custom Office Templates` as suggested.

I named the template created using the steps above `Book.xltx`

... and nothing happens.

Well almost nothing, anyway. The new template `Book` is available under Personal Themes, but it's not used automatically as I intended.

It's still a normal sheet when I create a new sheet, it didn't use the custom template.

If I create a new sheet by selecting `Book` under Personal Templates, it does create it correct, using the custom theme.

*Note:* I'm using a `Danish` version of Excel, but [the Danish version of the same guide](https://support.office.com/da-dk/article/%C3%86ndre-et-tema-og-g%C3%B8re-det-til-standard-i-Word-eller-Excel-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904#__make_my_changes) also requires the template to be named `Book.xltx`.
I also tried setting the *default personal templates location* to `C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents\Custom Office-skabeloner` as suggested by the Danish guide, no change.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: when our company mandated that we use their PowerPoint templates *by default* we were instructed to save the template here:  %appdata%\microsoft\templates

Comment: Thank you for the info. It's not what I need for this question, but I will need it as a part of the project so it's very helpful :-)

Comment: Just tried it, and it doesn't seem to work :-( Nothing happened when saving the PowerPoint template in that folder (or the Danish equivalent).

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/excel-2016-change-default-workbook-template/edc6bdaa-98d3-4e82-9ec7-60d2bb2f4bc4?rtAction=1497717332787) from HansV. It worked for me.

> Create a workbook with the number of worksheets you want, specify the styles etc.  Save it as a template named Book.xltx in the folder `%appdata%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`.
>   The name `Book.xltx` is mandatory but it depends on the interface language. In the French version it would be `Livre.xltx`, and in the German version `Buch.xltx`.

Comment: Damn, another language-specific registry name in Office *sigh*. I'll have to find where in the registry the name of the template is stored first then :-/